# Isometry and Extreme points

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is a Hilbert space and either $T$ or $T^*$ is an isometry, show that T is an extreme point of the closed unit ball of $B(X)$ where $B(X)$ is bounded linear functionals on $X$.

Can I get some hints?

Answer (score 4):

The key fact you want to use is that a Hilbert space is [strictly convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space).  This means that if $x,y\in X$ are distinct unit vectors and $0<t<1$, then $\|tx+(1-t)y\|<1$ (note that this inequality holds with $\leq$ for any normed space, so the key thing here is that the inequality is strict).

To apply this to the problem, suppose $T$ is an isometry and can be written as a convex combination $tA+(1-t)B$ for $A,B\in B(X)$ of norm $\leq 1$.  Now apply $T$ to an arbitrary unit vector and see what you can learn using strict convexity.